# Jersey serialize inherited property twice

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I have a java bean without any annotations. And I have a class inherited from this bean with JAXB annotations.

Jersey (JAX-RS) serialize the second class to JSON. And inherited properties occur in JSON twice: with name from `XmlElement` annotation and with 'camel-case' name of java-bean property. Here is a code which illustrates this:

```
class MyBean {

   private Integer beanField;

   public Integer getBeanField() { return beanField; }

   public void setBeanField(Integer value) { this.beanField = value; }

}

@XmlRootElement
class AnnotatedBean extends MyBean {

  @Override
  @XmlElement(name="field")
  public Integer getBeanField() { return super.getBeanField(); }
}
```

}

After serialization I get the next JSON:

```
{ 
   "field" : 5,
   "beanField" : 5
}
```

(while I want it to contain only one field with name `field`).

I investigated JAXB marshaller implementation and found that it marshals properties from all superclasses of the given class (and that means that it's impossible to get rid of the odd `beanField` property in my example).

But I still hope that I could miss something. Is there a way to serialize only annotated properties?

Answer (score 4):

To get only the annotated properties use XmlAccessType.NONE:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement
class AnnotatedBean extends MyBean {
    ...
}
```

---

***Mapping the 3rd Party Class Using Externalized Metadata***

You could use the [external metadata extension](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html) in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy), I'm the tech lead.  It allows you to provide metadata for 3rd party classes.  For this example the metadata will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="third.party.package">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="MyBean" xml-transient="true"/>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

To use MOXy you need to add a file named jaxb.properties in with your model classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

The following article has instructions on configuring MOXy to work with Jersery:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html

***Context Resolver - Leveraging the Metadata***

You would need to use a ContextResolver to get your JAXBContext to leverage the external bindings file.  The metadata is specified through a property when the JAXBContext is instantiated:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;

@Provider
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public class AnnotatedBeanContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    public PurchaseOrderContextResolver() {
        try {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextFactory.ECLIPSELINK_OXM_XML_KEY, new File("src/blog/bindingfile/binding.xml"));
        jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {AnnotatedBean.class}, properties);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> clazz) {
        if(AnnotatedBean.class == clazz) {
            return jaxbContext;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've already tried this option. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Thank you, Blaise. Your first example is exactly what I was looking for. I tried to edit a minor typo in there, but I'm restricted from doing so without peer review. The first annotation should read, "@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)", as I'm sure you're aware